# Is it acceptable to contact people from an old postdoc interview and ask if a job is still available?

Tags: job

Is it normal to contact people from an old postdoc position interview and ask if a job is still available? Last time I withdrew my application before results were announced. I was from a different country, had some family issues etc.

I noted that some positions in academia remain unfilled for longer periods of time (several month to more than one year), because they cannot hire the right person, I suppose.

**Is it a good idea to contact the main member of the selection comittee (project leader) and ask directly if that particular postdoc is still available?** They have a webpage with open positions but none is related to what I am capable of doing. I wonder if they found the right person for that older job, or that person could leave before the contract expired etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's totally fine to write a short note asking if the position is still available. The worst that will happen would be your e-mail gets deleted and never replied to. Even if the original interview was some time ago, you could still phrase the e-mail as "wondering if there are any new open positions in your lab for X."

In your specific case, because you applied, dropped out, and then are re-expressing your interest, the potential hiring faculty member would probably be a bit wary of your sincerity. I.e. if you dropped out once, what's to say you wouldn't drop out a second time, this time after the faculty member goes through the time and expense to hire you, get you set up in the lab, etc.?

Therefore, you should go ahead and write the letter, but be prepared to justify why this application is different from your previous aborted one.

Answer (score 3):

> They have a webpage with open positions but none is related to what I am capable of doing. I wonder if they found the right person for that older job, or that person could leave before the contract expired etc.

Contacting the project leader when they are no longer advertising for the postdoc is probably pointless. If the position were open, they would list it. If they don't list it, they no longer need someone.

> Is it normal to contact people from an old postdoc position interview and ask if a job is still available?

That's a different issue, since it's a question of etiquette. No, it's not "normal" in the sense that few people do it. Hidden in this question is another: "will it do any harm?" That depends on the project leader. For most, it probably does no harm to remind them of your existence.

But there are more effective ways of doing that. It begins with learning as much as you can about the project leader's research. Then send a note to the project leader about how much you value their research (assuming you do) and that you had liked  idea of working together, and regretted having to drop out. That would allay any misunderstanding. You could even say that you hope at some point to have the chance of working together in future. If they have an opening, they will let you know. And if one comes up in the near future, they'll remember you.